# angular 4 router without router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular4-router

I am currently implementing a custom state management in angular 4 based on angular router, basically without any *router-outlet* attaching and detaching components myself based on routing events.

It works fine until i try to navigate from a route with parameters to the same route with different parameters, then it crashes.

[This plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/brxSsU9xjjWJNwwA6VWq?p=preview) ( watch the console ) explains my situation. Navigating from '*crisis center*' to '*heroes*' is fine, navigating from '*heroes*' to '*hero 11*' is fine, navigating from '*hero11*' to '*hero12*' throws the error

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'component' of null`

I know the router is supposed to work with an outlet, but i think it's weird that without  it works partially, so I'm not even sure if this can be considered a bug or desired behavior.

I'm wondering if there's some configuration option that would allow this particular situation or should i just use another routing library and avoid the angular router?

Answer (score 2):

This issue is solved by adding a '**never**' configuration parameter to the Route's **runGuardsAndResolvers** configuration option, as seen in [this commit](https://github.com/jurito/angular/commit/1d7b9f93ec91f488366d86be7c0ce196f32ed956).