# Is it safe to use the Angular 5 router without a router-outlet?

Tags: angular, routes

The closest I could find to a question on this same subject was this: [angular 4 router without router-outlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45216208/angular-4-router-without-router-outlet)

...but it's about an experimental feature in Angular 4 that doesn't seem to be supported anymore.

I have a existing astronomy web app (http://skyviewcafe.com/) that doesn't use routing at all. All of the various functionality is accessed through a tabbed interface that doesn't change the route.

I want to be able to use a URL to specify which tabbed panel comes up, however, and eventually go further than that with URLs that set time and location and viewing options, so a URL can be used by one person to show another person a particular view of an astronomical event.

So far it looks like I'm getting away without a router outlet just fine: http://test.skyviewcafe.com/

Nothing I've tried so far trips up the app or throws any console exceptions. I'm simply subscribing to router events so I know when to change which tab is selected:

```
router.events.subscribe(event => {
  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    const url = event.url;
    const newTab = tabNames.map(name => '/' + name).indexOf(url);

    if (newTab >= 0)
      this.currentTab = newTab;
    else
      this.currentTab = CurrentTab.SKY;
  }
});
```

...and navigating to a route when a tab is selected:

```
public set currentTab(newTab: CurrentTab) {
  if (this._currentTab.getValue() !== newTab) {
    this._currentTab.next(newTab);
    this.router.navigate(['/' + tabNames[this._currentTab.getValue()]]);
  }
}
```

I'm happy with the results, but I'm left with the nagging feeling that *it just isn't right* to do routing this way.

If the tabbed view is the only thing I'm changing with each route, what would I do to use a router outlet? Make the tabs nothing more than decorative, not actually owning any tabbed panels, replacing the whole area below the tabs with the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`?